# Add item to favorites and save it in a Cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, save

I have this item:

```
<li><a style="display: none">Movie</a><div id="movie-item" class="filterDiv thriller science-fiction action horror war 2018"></div></li>
```

And a button that allows you to save that item in Favorites:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('movie-item').item.classList.add('favorites');">Mark as favorite</button>
```

That works perfect, because when I click on 'Favorites' section, the item appears correctly! 
But the problem is: I want to create a Cookie that saves that the item was marked as favorite.

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzOmNe#anon-login

Someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: I recommend using localStorage. You can save the selection as a string and then load that saved item back into the page at a later date.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: If it's a list of items, then you could use something like JSON stringify to turn the information into a string and back from a string using the JSON parse command. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend to use cookies. You should use localStorage instead.

```js
function saveFav () {

  document.getElementById('movie-item').classList.add('favorites');
  
  // Save
  localStorage.setItem('favorites', 'movie');
  // Get
  var fav = localStorage.getItem('favorites');
  console.log(fav);
}
```

```html
<li><a style="display: none">Movie</a><div id="movie-item" class="filterDiv thriller science-fiction action horror war 2018"></div></li>

<button onclick="saveFav()">Mark as favorite</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't works for me, check this pen to understand better:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzOmNe#anon-login

Comment: Open console and see... The saved data will be stored in the "fav" variable after clicking the "mark BMW as Favorite" button.
You can get the marked item by calling `localStorage.getItem('favorites')` and do what you want....

Answer (score 0):

you can create cookie by this line

```
document.cookie = "cookieName=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```